# Enum Type variable BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums

I ran into this issue:

I defined a enum type in the header file:

```
typedef enum {
    aView,
    bView,
    cView
} SCViewType;
```

and then in my header file, I have:

```
@property (nonatomic) SCViewType currentView;
```

In my `.m` file, I have this:

```
- (void) setCurrentView: (SCViewType) view
{
    self.currentView = view;
}
```

And this `self.currentView = view` line got BAD_ACCESS error...

Please point me what's wrong with this implementation, and what I should do to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Is that all you do in your `setCurrentView:` method? If so, why override the synthesized setter method for the property?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `self.currentView = view;`. Objective-C will convert to `- (void) setCurrentView: (SCViewType) view` automatically. So this method will be called again and again.

Just modify the code to:

```
- (void) setCurrentView: (SCViewType) view
{
    _currentView = view;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that of the OP also implements the getter method, the ivar won't exist unless it is added explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The "self." will call the the setter method and end up in endless loop.
[More detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494157/in-objective-c-on-ios-what-is-the-style-difference-between-self-foo-and-fo)